# My web request is taking longer than XDebug log says

Tags: php, mysql, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

I'm working on a PHP/MySql website with a poorly performing function. I'm trying to get a breakdown of where time is being lost. The web request takes 13 seconds.

If I use the chrome network tab or fiddler, 99% of the time is spent "Waiting" so this isn't helpful.

I've installed XDebug and temporarily turned on profiling to debug this issue. I'm analyzing the logs in WinCacheGrind which state that the requests in total take 1.5 seconds.

Where else can I look and how can I work out what is taking the most time?

Thanks in advance!